# Model 433 MHz helix antenna with 4nec2

Tags: antenna

I am trying to model a simple helix antenna with 4nec2 program but I am getting very different results from the datasheet specs: in particular SWR is stated to be less than 1.8 with a gain between 2 and 3 dBi. This is instead what I am getting:

[image: 4nec2 main window]

The antenna looks like this:

[image: antenna image]

The nec file is:

```
CE
SY L=0.0205 'Length of helix
SY S=0.001  'Pitch
SY R=0.0003 'Wire radius
SY N=(L-2*R)/S  'Turns
SY D=0.005  'Helix diameter
SY L1=0.008 'Length of base wire
SY L2=0.0055    'Length wire to be soldered
GW  1   3   0   0   -L1 0   L2  -L1 R
GW  2   1   0   0   0   0   0   -L1 R
GW  3   1   D/2 0   0   0   0   0   R
GH  4   N*12    S   L   D/2 D/2 D/2 D/2 R
GM  0   0   -90 0   0   0   L1  L2  0   
GE  1
GN  1
EK
EX  0   1   2   0   1   0   0
FR  0   0   0   0   433 0
EN
```

I tried several ground settings but wasn't able to achieve a good SWR value.

Edit: I tried adding a reflector but it doesn't help.

[image: Antenna with reflector]

This is the real antenna:

[image: Real antenna]

Comment: Where is the GND plane or at least a GND wire for the return path of the displacement current?

Comment: @EnricoMigliore I tried using a perfect ground connected to the antenna at z=0 but still the results aren’t similar to the real antenna. For what I know the PCB  should be considered as a reflector. Is the ground the right way to achieve this behavior?

Comment: With a perfect ground connected at z=0 the SWR50 drops to 1417.

Comment: There's something wrong here: SWR can't be that high. Try opening a sample project and play with it to get more experience with that simulator program.

Comment: I tried reducing the number of segment per turn to 4 and the SWR became 480. Could it be a numerical problem?

Comment: No numerical problem at all. An SWR that big means that you are not pushing and pulling electrons into the antenna and that means no radiation.

Comment: @EnricoMigliore You sure? [See this](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/20152/how-to-correctly-model-a-small-helix-antenna)